# Fetch Records in Angular datatable

Tags: spring-boot, angular6

Im new to Angular and My Requirement is

A component includes a form with the field name call  "Brand" and a button to add the same record to database through angular service and there should be a datatable which is fetching all brand data from database to data table.

so by using fetchall method in ts file, i am assigning values to data table. im calling fetchall method to ngoninit() which helps me to show the data in table while component get initialized. to add record, i am using a method call addyear() and calling the same method to onSumbit(). my problem is when i add the record to database, i should be able to load newly added record to angular data table! since that method in ngoninit(), i have to refresh the browser to get the record in data table kindly give me a solution. for the back end, im using Spring boot with Postgres database

My Component TS file

```
    constructor(private brandService:BrandService,private toastyService: ToastyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.findbrand();
  }

  onSubmit()
  {
    this.saveBrand();
    this.submitted=true;
  }

  saveBrand()
  {
    this.brandService.addbrand(this.brand).subscribe
    (data=>this.addToast({title:'Record Has been added Successfully', msg:'', timeout: 5000, theme:'default', position:'top-right', type:'success'}),
    error=>this.addToast({title:'Record Not Added! Sorry', msg:'', timeout: 5000, theme:'default', position:'top-right', type:'error'}));
    this.brand=new Brand();
  }

  findbrand()
  {
    this.brandService.findbrand().subscribe(data=>this.data=data,error=>this.addToast({title:'Record Cannot be found! Sorry', msg:'', timeout: 5000, theme:'default', position:'top-right', type:'error'}));
  }
```

My Service.TS file

```
export class BrandService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  private baseUrl='http://localhost:8080/snazzy-engine/brand';

  addbrand(brand:object):Observable<any>
  {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}` + `/insert`, brand,{
      headers: {'schemaName':'test.'}
   });
  }

  findbrand():Observable<any>
  {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}` + `/find-all`,{
      headers: {'schemaName':'test.'}
   });
  }

  getbrandid(id: number): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/find-one/${id}`, {headers: 
   {'schemaName':'test.'}});
  }
}
```

My HTML File

```
<div class="table-content crm-table">
          <div class="project-table">
            <div id="crm-contact" class="dt-responsive">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                  <div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                  <div style="text-align: right;">
                    <label>Search:
                      <input type="search" [(ngModel)]="filterQuery" class="form-control input-sm full-data-search" placeholder="Search name">
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="panel-heading">User information</div>-->
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm" [mfData]="data | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage" [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy"
                  [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
                  <thead class="thead-dark text-center">
                    <tr>
                      <th style="width:10%">
                        <mfDefaultSorter by="brandId">Brand ID</mfDefaultSorter>
                      </th>

                      <th style="width:70%">
                        <mfDefaultSorter by="name">Brand Name</mfDefaultSorter>
                      </th>
                      <th style="width:10%">
                        <mfDefaultSorter by="more">More</mfDefaultSorter>
                      </th>
                      <th style="width:10%">
                        <mfDefaultSorter by="checkbox">Delete</mfDefaultSorter>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i = index;">
                      <td>{{item.brandId}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.brand}}</td>
                      <td class="action-icon">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="findybrandid(item.brandId);modalDefault.show();">
                            edit
                            </button>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="checkbox text-center">
                          <label><input type="checkbox" value=""></label>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="10">
                        <mfBootstrapPaginator class="pagination-main f-right"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
              <button class="btn btn-out btn-danger ripple light"><i class="icofont icofont-check-circled"></i>Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as the data is coming from the server through api it will show only the page refreshes, there are two ways through which you can acheive your goal. first one is use firebase as your database, second option is use array push method  after adding data into the database

Comment: share your code so we can help you more

Comment: i have shared my code!pls help

Comment: pls share all the code (component, service and html) so that i can provide you a better answer

Comment: i have shared the code! all i want is the moment i add the record, i should be able to fetch it to  data table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
saveBrand()
{
    this.brandService.addbrand(this.brand)
    .subscribe(
        data => this.addToast(
            {
                title:'Record Has been added Successfully', 
                msg:'', 
                timeout: 5000, 
                theme:'default', 
                position:'top-right', 
                type:'success'
            }),
        error => this.addToast(
            {
                title:'Record Not Added! Sorry', 
                msg:'', 
                timeout: 5000, 
                theme:'default', 
                position:'top-right', 
                type:'error'
            })
    );
    this.data.push(this.brand); /*change: push new data into an array*/
    this.brand=new Brand();
}
```